# Webview loses virtualkeyboard in chromeos kiosk

Tags: google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

Ive created a web app using a webview tag that loads a hosted web application and deployed ona  chromebox. I have given the app the webview,power and idle permissions.

When clicking (or touching) an input within the webview, the chromeos virtual keyboard fails to appear. Is there another required permission? Am I missing something?